# 2000s movie with a dorky boy who takes a potion that turns him into a cooler guy to impress a girl

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie from my childhood in the mid-2000s to maybe early-2010s. This movie was based in a futuristic setting and the main character was a boy. He went to a school where they learn a lot about technology. I remember that he is quite dorky and somehow turns into another cooler guy to impress a girl by taking some potion. I also remember a scene where students race like bikes on a course.

I know it is not *[Meet the Robinsons](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0396555/)* (2008).

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Since you mentioned _Meet the Robinsons_, was this animated or live-action?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is ***[The Nutty Professor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0839930/)*** (2008).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nutty_Professor_(2008_film)):

> *The Nutty Professor* (also known as *The Nutty Professor: Facing the Fear* and *The Nutty Professor II*) is a 2008 computer-animated comedy sequel to the 1963 Jerry Lewis comedy of the same name and based on the story *Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde* by Robert Louis Stevenson, produced by Rainmaker Entertainment and The Weinstein Company and distributed by Genius Products. Lewis reprises his role of Julius Kelp and produces the film. Drake Bell plays the voice of Harold Kelp, Julius' grandson.
>
> The film was released direct-to-video on November 25, 2008.

> **Harold Kelp is a young inventor.** He is frequently attacked in his visions by his fear, which takes the form of a group of burly dodgeball players as well as a black monster. After encountering an angry mob involved in his bad inventions, **Harold is informed by his robot assistant, Polly that he will be sent away to a science academy where his grandfather, Julius Kelp has taken up a duty as Professor.**
>
> **Upon his arrival, Harold befriends a duo of misfits, Zeke and Ned who welcomes him into their dorm, has a run in with a bully named Brad and meets a beautiful girl named Polly McGregor whom he becomes enamoured with. Wanting to impress Polly, Harold gets his hands on his grandfather's secret elixir, the Secrets of Love, which he believes will help him win her affection. He drinks it, unleashing his cooler, hipper alter ego Jack, who causes mischief.**
>
> Jack starts out popular with the students, but his behavior and ego get out of hand. Also, because of Jack, Harold is failing classes. When he learns of Harold's problem, Julius transforms into Buddy Love to teach Harold to be himself. Later on, Harold's fear is accidentally brought to life by one of Julius' inventions, but he manages to defeat it by facing it.
>
> Jack says good-bye to Harold and disappears into him, leaving Harold to share a kiss with Polly.

You mentioned *Meet the Robinsons* in the question, which made me think you were looking for a computer-animated film, although you didn't state that directly.

This film appears to hit all the plot points you mentioned in your description, including the bike-racing scene, which begins at around 48 minutes into the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a Disney Channel Original Movie from 1999 called ***[Genius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genius_(1999_film))***!

> *Genius* is a 1999 Disney Channel Original Movie (DCOM) directed by Rod Daniel. The film stars Trevor Morgan and Emmy Rossum, and premiered on Disney Channel on August 21, 1999. In the film, Morgan portrays a genius who enrolls in college at the age of 12 and takes on a bad boy image in an attempt to gain friends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how this matches the OP's description of the film they asked about. For example, does _Genius_ feature a bike race?

Answer (score -4):

Is it "Ivan the Incredible"
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2322457/

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?